# Printing String Array in Android, Eclipse

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Below is my array. Just need to know how to print them out using canvas.drawText.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
String [] Words = {
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "pear",
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue",
};
```

** Edited. Sorry, i just need to print 1 String per time. my mistake for not stating so earlier.

**EDITED:**

i tried something like this:

```
canvas.drawText(Words[wordGenerator(m)], 100, 100, null);
```

with the following func:

```
private int wordGenerator(int length) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    length = (int)(Math.random()*6);
    return length;
}
```

it crashes with the following error on logCat:

- E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
- E/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.NullPointerException
- E/AndroidRuntime(447):   at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Native Method)
- E/AndroidRuntime(447):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

Comment: just need to print out 1 string per time. i have a random generator func to random which string to be printed, just need to know how.

Comment: **canvas.drawText(words[randomNum()]) ?**

Comment: Can you paste the LogCat output?

Answer (score 1):

use TextUtils.join or TextUtils.concat

### Edit

like sandy pointed out in the comments,

```
canvas.drawText(words[rand.nextInt(words.length()]);
```

should do

### Edit (agains)

According to your last edit, this should be the way to go

```
canvas.drawText(words[wordGenerator(words.length());
```

Comment: i tried this line of code, canvas.drawText(Words[wordGenerator.nextInt(Words.length()]);
and i had error at the length() asking me to change it to a length.
Once i change it, i had this error: Cannot invoke nextInt(int) on the primitive type int. The drawText is showing an error as well: Cannot invoke nextInt(int) on the primitive type int